# OpenMP with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

My makefile is as follows:

```
BINDIR=/path/to/bin

BK = f1.c f2.c f3.c
BKo= f1.o f2.o f3.o    
kl: kl.c $(BK)
        @echo "*** Numerical solution ***"
        gcc -fopenmp -c kl.c $(BK)
        gcc -fopenmp -o $(BINDIR)/kl kl.o $(BKo) -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
        @echo "*** OK ***"
```

Is -fopenmp included in a correct way in two gcc commands?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what's your real problem?

Comment: I think you expect BLAS operation to be parallelized while it is not, isn't it? Note that AFAIK GSL BLAS is not parallelized and also generally quite slow. You can use OpenBLAS, BLIS or the Intel MKL as a (parallel) replacement.